# How many ways can you arrange 4 physics book and 5 math books so that the physics book are next to each other?

Tags: combinations

How many ways can you arrange 4 physics book and 5 math books so that the physics book are next to each other?

So I know the arrangements can be,

PPPPMMMMM
MPPPPMMMM
MMPPPPMMM
MMMPPPPMM
MMMMMPPPP

4! * 5! = 2880 ways
There are 4 ways to arrange the physics book and 5 ways to arrange the others so 4! * 5!. I'm not sure if that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Places to put the first Physics book:  6

Arrangements of Physics books:  4!

Arrangements of math books 5!

---

Total number of arrangements; $6\cdot 4! 5! = 17280$.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much!

Comment: There are six places to place the first physics book since the number of math books that can be placed before the first physics book can range from $0$ to $5$, so your answer should be $6 \cdot 4!5!$.

Answer (score 3):

Doing it the long way, like you (but correctly !),

$\fbox{PPPP}MMMMM$

$M\fbox{PPPP}MMMM$

$MM\fbox{PPPP}MMM$

$MMM\fbox{PPPP}MM$

$MMMM\fbox{PPPP}M$

$MMMMM\fbox{PPPP}$

$6*4!*5!=17,280$

The short way is to realize that the *block* of $4$ Physics books have **six** places to start ($4$ gaps between $5$ Math books $+ 2$ ends) and then permute both groups, so (as before) $6*4!*5!$ ways

Comment: Thanks for the catch: fencepost!

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to think of it, for me at least.
Let "p" and "m" represent the physics and math books respectively.
and let $P$ represent the physics books together.
Then, there are 4! ways to arrange $P$ and 6! ways to arrange the remaining books like so:

- Pmmmmm
- mPmmmm
- mmPmmm
- mmmPmm
- mmmmPm
- mmmmmP

for a total of 6!4!=17280 ways.  Same answer, just a slightly different way of thinking about it.